# How to aggregate multiple arrays in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, user-defined-functions, azure-stream-analytics

I have a table that looks like this:

```
"A" : [1,2,3],
"A" : [4,5,6],
"A" : [7,8,9],
"B" : [10,11,12]
"B" : [13,14,15]
"B" : [16,17,18]
```

and i need it to look likes this:

```
"A" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
"B" : [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
```

How can i merge the arrays based on their letter in stream analytics? All the aggregate functions i've tried do not help.

Thanks -

Comment: If what you are saying here is to have a column, containing comma separated values, then you should know that it is against the SQL Normalization rules, especially the 1st rule saying that "Each cell should be single valued".

Comment: Hi, is the final output 2 columns or 1?

Comment: @SteveC 2 columns. Sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: Ok I wasn't sure what the colon represented.  My answer below works and returns 2 columns :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to GROUP BY <column with the "A", "B"> and use COLLECT() as an aggregate. This will give you {name : "A", val : [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ] }, ...

And then use a JavaScript UDF to flatten the array of arrays.

Here are some links to documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/collect-azure-stream-analytics

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I think fits

```
drop table if exists dbo.test_table;
go
create table dbo.test_table(
  letter        char(3) not null,
  string        varchar(20) not null);

insert dbo.test_table(letter, string) values
('"A"', '[1,2,3]'),
('"A"', '[4,5,6]'),
('"A"', '[7,8,9]'),
('"B"', '[10,11,12]'),
('"B"', '[12,14,15]'),
('"B"', '[16,17,18]');

select letter, concat('[', string_agg(cast(intg.value as varchar(9)),',') within group (order by intg.value), ']') colName
from dbo.test_table t
     cross apply
     string_split(substring(string, 2, len(string)-2),',') intg
group by letter;
```

Results

```
letter  colName
"A"     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
"B"     [10,11,12,12,14,15,16,17,18]
```

Comment: I dont see this working in Azure Stream Analytics. If it was standard SQL sure. But, for example, you need to use GROUP BY in ASA with a time window. You also cannot use WITHIN.

Comment: Aah it's marked as tsql.  Yeah I couldn't answer for another platform